# How to eliminate rows from table which i dont want

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is My table. I want particular rows of mobile number having only one record of escalated call and close call

```
Mobile_No   Call_Time           Pick_Time           Close_Time        Call_Duration   CallStatus
7777777777  23-11-2016 16:47    23-11-2016 16:47    NULL              NULL             ATTEND
8080808080  21-11-2016 12:59    21-11-2016 13:02    21-11-2016 13:03  0.001446759      ESCALATE
8080808080  21-11-2016 12:59    21-11-2016 13:03    NULL              NULL             ESCALATE
8087617483  21-11-2016 13:05    23-11-2016 16:02    23-11-2016 16:02  00:00:18         CLOSE
8087617483  21-11-2016 13:05    23-11-2016 16:02    NULL              NULL             CLOSE
8655246108  21-11-2016 13:05    22-11-2016 10:59    23-11-2016 16:39  30:1780:106836   CLOSE
8655246108  21-11-2016 13:05    23-11-2016 16:39    24-11-2016 11:44  19:1145:68698    CLOSE
9167485255  21-11-2016 13:07    23-11-2016 16:34    23-11-2016 16:38  0.005659722      ESCALATE
9167485255  21-11-2016 13:07    23-11-2016 16:38    NULL              NULL             ESCALATE
9890473692  21-11-2016 13:07    22-11-2016 11:36    22-11-2016 11:53  0.023622685      CLOSE
9890473692  21-11-2016 13:07    22-11-2016 11:53    24-11-2016 11:31  48:2858:171423   CLOSE
9890473692  24-11-2016 11:29    24-11-2016 11:31    24-11-2016 11:47  0.022337963      ATTEND
```

Now I want output as

```
Mobile_No   Call_Time           Pick_Time              Close_Time           Call_Duration    CallStatus
7777777777  2016-11-23 16:47:26 2016-11-23 16:47:43    NULL                 NULL             ATTEND
8080808080  2016-11-21 12:59:44 2016-11-21 13:02:15    2016-11-21 13:03:20  0:1:65           ESCALATE
8080808080  2016-11-21 12:59:44 2016-11-21 13:03:20    NULL                 NULL             ESCALATE
8087617483  2016-11-21 13:05:04 2016-11-23 16:02:35    2016-11-23 16:02:53  0:0:18           CLOSE
8087617483  2016-11-21 13:05:04 2016-11-23 16:02:53    NULL                 NULL             CLOSE
8655246108  2016-11-21 13:05:59 2016-11-22 10:59:16    2016-11-23 16:39:52  30:1780:106836   CLOSE 
8655246108  2016-11-21 13:05:59 2016-11-23 16:39:52    2016-11-24 11:44:50  19:1145:68698    CLOSE
9167485255  2016-11-21 13:07:57 2016-11-23 16:34:16    2016-11-23 16:38:25  0:4:249 ESCALATE
9167485255  2016-11-21 13:07:57 2016-11-23 16:38:25     NULL                NULL             ESCALATE
9890473692  2016-11-21 13:07:00 2016-11-22 11:36:56    2016-11-22 11:53:57  0:17:1021         CLOSE
9890473692  2016-11-21 13:07:00 2016-11-22 11:53:57    2016-11-24 11:31:00  48:2858:171423  CLOSE
9890473692  2016-11-24 11:29:20 2016-11-24 11:31:00     2016-11-24 11:47:10 0:16:970         ATTEND
```

Comment: Check your question both your table data and output also same what your expected output

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. It sounds like you want one record for each mobile number (is that your unique field?) and then return one appearance of 'escalated' and one appearance of 'close', is that correct? Also, what have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on? What if a call has multiple entries for call status 'close', what's your criteria on which to keep?

Comment: the only differences are date formats and duration once as decimal hours and once as time format. what exactly do you expect? what do you want to eliminate?

Comment: If you want people to take _their_ time to help you, you should take some of _your_ time to write a clear question. Do you want to eliminate the data in your query? If yes, what is the query? Or you want to delete the existing data in your table? What is the code you have tried? And you shouldn't expect people to sift through your data. Make clear where the differences are. I don't see any.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select Mobile_No,to_char(Call_Time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh12:mm:ss'),Pick_Time,Close_Time,Call_Duration,CallStatus from table where Mobile_No in
(select Mobile_No  from table having (select count(*) from table where callstatus ='escalate')=1 and having (select count(*) from table where callstatus ='close')=1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        CREATE TABLE Table11
    (Mobile_No bigint, Call_Time varchar(16), Pick_Time varchar(16), Close_Time varchar(16), Call_Duration varchar(14), CallStatus varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Table11 (Mobile_No, Call_Time, Pick_Time, Close_Time, Call_Duration, CallStatus) VALUES
    (7777777777, '23-11-2016 16:47', '23-11-2016 16:47', NULL, NULL, 'ATTEND'),
    (8080808080, '21-11-2016 12:59', '21-11-2016 13:02', '21-11-2016 13:03', '0.001446759', 'ESCALATE'),
    (8080808080, '21-11-2016 12:59', '21-11-2016 13:03', NULL, NULL, 'ESCALATE'),
    (8087617483, '21-11-2016 13:05', '23-11-2016 16:02', '23-11-2016 16:02', '00:00:18', 'CLOSE'),
    (8087617483, '21-11-2016 13:05', '23-11-2016 16:02', NULL, NULL, 'CLOSE'),
    (8655246108, '21-11-2016 13:05', '22-11-2016 10:59', '23-11-2016 16:39', '30:1780:106836', 'CLOSE'),
    (8655246108, '21-11-2016 13:05', '23-11-2016 16:39', '24-11-2016 11:44', '19:1145:68698', 'CLOSE'),
    (9167485255, '21-11-2016 13:07', '23-11-2016 16:34', '23-11-2016 16:38', '0.005659722', 'ESCALATE'),
    (9167485255, '21-11-2016 13:07', '23-11-2016 16:38', NULL, NULL, 'ESCALATE'),
    (9890473692, '21-11-2016 13:07', '22-11-2016 11:36', '22-11-2016 11:53', '0.023622685', 'CLOSE'),
    (9890473692, '21-11-2016 13:07', '22-11-2016 11:53', '24-11-2016 11:31', '48:2858:171423', 'CLOSE'),
    (9890473692, '24-11-2016 11:29', '24-11-2016 11:31', '24-11-2016 11:47', '0.022337963', 'ATTEND')
;
with cte as
(
select * ,row_number() over (partition by mobile_no,CallStatus order by call_time) as rn from Table11
)
select * from cte where rn=1 and CallStatus not in('ESCALATE','CLOSE')
```

output

```
Mobile_No   Call_Time   Pick_Time   Close_Time  Call_Duration   CallStatus  rn
8080808080  21-11-2016 12:59    21-11-2016 13:02    21-11-2016 13:03    0.001446759 ESCALATE    1
8087617483  21-11-2016 13:05    23-11-2016 16:02    23-11-2016 16:02    00:00:18    CLOSE   1
8655246108  21-11-2016 13:05    22-11-2016 10:59    23-11-2016 16:39    30:1780:106836  CLOSE   1
9167485255  21-11-2016 13:07    23-11-2016 16:34    23-11-2016 16:38    0.005659722 ESCALATE    1
9890473692  21-11-2016 13:07    22-11-2016 11:36    22-11-2016 11:53    0.023622685 CLOSE   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH cte as
(
    SELECT Mobile_No, Call_Time, Pick_Time, Close_Time, Call_Duration, CallStatus,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY Mobile_No,CallStatus ORDER     BY Call_Time) AS ROWNUM 
    FROM TableName
)
SELECT Mobile_No, Call_Time, Pick_Time, Close_Time, Call_Duration, CallStatus 
FROM cte
WHERE ROWNUM=1 and CallStatus <>'ATTEND'
```